# Add a volume and it mount using kubectl set volume command in statefulset

Tags: kubectl, volume

wanted to add following volume to an existing statefullset
'''

```
  - name: redissecret
    secret:
      secretName: zts-config-secret
      items:
        - key: password
          path:  redispasswd
          mode: 0644
```

....

### and Volume redissecret mount to the specific container maccontainer  as /redis :

'''

- mountPath: /redis
  name: redissecret
  '''

Tried with bellow command
'''
kubectl set volume sts/macservice --add -m /redis --source '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"volumes": [{"name": "redissecret","secret": {"items":[{"key":"password","mode":420,"path":"redispasswd"}],"secretName":"cts-config-secret"}}]}}}}' -c maccontainer
'''